# Cloud save? box.com/NextCloud/OwnCloud

Tags: encryption, cloud-storage

I need to keep notes that are personal (decisions, objectives, goals, ideas, projects) and I was thinking of using box.com which seems to be quite trustworthy, but how do I know that box.com respects the privacy of my data? Asking me this, I came up with the idea of using a free hosting service (I know a very stable one, without advertising and good terms of service), in this hosting service install NextCloud or OwnCloud with encryption enabled, this is enough to protect privacy of my notes? Is the encryption of these services reliable to protect the information? Do you think it is an efficient system or do you recommend something better?

Comment: This question probably wont get answered.I will only say that when using a third party,you will have to trust that said 3rd party.

Comment: what box.com or xyz.com does with your data is on them/local laws/ethics/security practices etc.

Comment: If you don't care about metadata (file names...), you can use a note encryption program and load the encrypted text into the cloud of any provider. The former LockNote is no longer maintained, but you can find many alternatives. NextCloud with encryption enabled is a good option. You can also use it together with text encryption programs.

Comment: @BeloumiX Thank you! It is a good idea, I had not thought about encrypting the text, I would just have to find some Android application with this feature.
It seems that using encryption in NextCloud is not a good idea since it corrupts the files as I could read in the NextCloud official forum and in GitHub you can see that they have multiple problems to solve with encryption:
https://github.com/nextcloud/server/labels/feature%3A%20encryption%20%28server-side%29